# How would a fantasy city look if it were designed to house dragons

Tags: society, magic, medieval, dragons, architecture

So currently I'm writing a book and the main city has humans and dragons coexisting.
What I want to know is what features would need to be included in order to make this possible

Specifically food and living space

DETAILS

Dragons are of all ages from eggs to adults

Magic is available

This system has been going on for a long time

They have plenty of land and a ocean

Both groups can work together well

Technology is medieval however many things can be supplemented with magic

Comment: Greetings & welcome!  Be sure to take a look at the [tour] and [help]. Right now your query is a little unfocused. Questions beginning with "how would it..." generally means you're kind of fishing for opinions. I'd like you to edit your question down so that you're focusing on one specific problem. Like width of streets & alleys. Also, since we only take one question at a time, I'd suggest you delete the secondary question entirely. We will simply assume, since you're asking, that in your world this set-up is possible.

Comment: It would be... well, big. I recommend reading Lackey's [Dragon Jousters series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dragon_Jousters_Series) or Hobb's [Rain Wild Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Keeper), both of which IIRC feature such construction. (I *know* Hobb's does.) There are some examples of *rooms* for dragons in Paolini's [Inheritance Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inheritance_Cycle) also, but not really entire cities.